# securing a shell script from accessing passwords

Tags: linux, security, shell

As a very new bash scripts' developer, I am wondering what are the means of securing access to a certain script that has let's say passwords inside it. I want the script to be executable in the shell, but I dont want anyone to have access to the inner content of it.

Comment: Don't put passwords to scripts. Use passwordless access (agents).

Comment: The only advice you can get is to use agents as @choroba wisely said. Otherwise, there's no definite answer to your question, as you're not giving any code, any tools you're using that need the password etc..

Comment: Shell scripts in particular are infamously tricky for secure peogramming. But the general principle is to not store passwords in your programs.

Comment: In order to run a script, the user must be able to read it. So there is no completely effective way to put sensitive data inside a script and keep it hidden. There are obfuscation techniques, and techniques that attempt to add security by utilizing techniques like `sudo`, but it's difficult to come up with a bullet-proof way to keep sensitive data in plain-text form inside a file of any sort. Don't do it - re-spin your design instead...